# Change line spacing from <br> to other line spacing methods in css

Tags: css, html

I am writing an HTML5 page at the moment, I'm having an issue switching format from using br for line spacing to line-height, padding, or margin (whichever is easier). Everything is inside of a form and fieldset tag I do not want every line to be on their own, just some. Some text I do want next to each other because I am making a form that has radio buttons and check boxes. But instead of using br tags how I can switch that out to line-height, padding, or margin in css.

```
<form>
<fieldset class = "top">
Please Select a car: <br>
<input type="radio" name="car" value="truck">truck
<input type="radio" name="car" value="van">van
<input type="radio" name="car" value="suv">suv<br>
<input type="radio" name="car" value="coupe">coupe
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Blue">Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">red
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Orange">Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="black">Black
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Green">green
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="brown">brown
<br>
<br>
```

....

Comment: whats wrong with a <br> tag?

Comment: It's really going to depend on the specifics of what you're trying to do, I suggest you include an example of what you tried and what was the result.

Comment: Post the HTML, and indent each line by an (additional) four spaces, preceding, and following, the code with an empty line. Or, for in-line code, surround the code with back-ticks `\` // your code here\``. For more advice, see the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: If you want to change the line spacing then line-height is really the only correct answer...

Comment: There is the code example

Comment: @david can you show me using my code above an example as to how to get the same result as using br by using line height in css?

Comment: i think you'll need something else around your blocks of inputs to tell the browser where these extra spaces need to be, like div tags with a class that includes an appropriate margin-bottom or a p tag.

Comment: `<br>` is not a line spacing method; it simply ends a line, without affecting line spacing at all. It is unclear what you wish to accomplish and why the current markup is used (it creates an odd appearance). The question should be reformulated in its entirety, including its title.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a fieldset for each group of radios so you can control them more precisely, put margin only around your group and etc.

You can use labels and span around the label/input groups, so you can control them better.

```
<span>
    <label for="name">Value</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1"/>
</span>
```

Also if you use a class specific for your input, you can make it display in block, like this:

```
input.block {
    display: block;
}
```

then if you put this class block on your input the label will stay in another line...

For a bigger picture see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BxwNL/1/

**Update: another solution according to cinnamon comment**

You can also use a list for your items, but it would make sense if you grouped them according to their properties, like a list for the colours, a list for the types...

The usage would be like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Value</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="name2">Value2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="2"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle example for the list solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/BxwNL/2/

Comment: Should have used a list for marking up a list of elements, not a bunch of spans.  Also, your labels are missing a `for` attribute (though it is optional if the label is containing the input it matches).

Comment: @cimmanon - That's just going to make things harder. If there's a semantic list of the content for the checkboxes at all, it must include blus, red, orange, black, green and brown in a single list. How are you then going to group those li's into pairs?

Comment: The list solutions would be more elegant, but as alohci said his groups are not really logic so the list would lose sense, I will update the answer and put that option too

Comment: @Alohci The elements are clearly marked up for presentational purposes in the OP, not because they have a relationship.  Colors and vehicles are clearly 2 distinct lists.